# Error: Cannot find module 'module-name' - npm creating a shortcut for packages when install it

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I hope someone help me i searched a lot but not found the answer i was installed `node v12.9.1` and installed some packages like `express`, `fluent-ffmpeg`, `ffmpeg`, `request`, `axios` after installing they was working good but yesterday i tried to run a file but it's give

```
Error: can't find module 'module-name'
```

I said maybe there's something wrong is happened so i removed it then installed `v10.23.0` but i found the problem is that when i run `npm install <package-name>` it's creating a shortcut with the package name that's why it's getting me this error and When i try to open the package folder it's also give the following error

[image: Error Message]

and even if i re installed the packages it's will tell me that there's some packages updated but when require it give the following error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'fluent-ffmpeg'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\v\v.js:1:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

I don't know where's the problem can anyone help me

Here's some images for packages

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B05Is.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqhGu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wf8W.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2GTR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Delete node_modules folder, find out which node version you need to use, switch to that version, then reinstall the packages when you're on the correct node version. Then try `npm start` again. [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) is a good package for changing between node versions.

Comment: I'm tried to remove it and node_modules then installed it again but it's restore node_modules folder and creating shortcuts for packages and about versions both is working `v12.9.1`, `v10.23.0`

Comment: I've just noticed it seems like you're running `npm install` from within your Windows user folder, is that right? Do you have a particular project folder that it should be running instead?